# i want to transform this plot to this

Tags: r, ggplot2

using this code want to transform the plot

```
ggplot(melteddata,aes(x=date, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_col(width=0.3,position = position_nudge(x=-0.2))+theme(legend.position="top")+ggtitle("wtg83363")+
  geom_col(melteddata2,mapping = aes(x=date,y=value,fill=variable),width=0.3,position = position_nudge(x=+0.2))+theme(legend.position="top")+scale_fill_manual(values=pal)+facet_wrap(~blade, scales="free_x", nrow=1)+labs(x="UT Scan Date", y="Wedge Delamination Count [-]")
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOUrv.gif this to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9xvB.png

Comment: Welcome to SO, Eliyas!  You will be most likely to get your question answered if you follow the [helpful advice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking questions and create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: thanks for editing my question @DaveArmstrong but i will be more happy if u help me to solve this

Comment: I would be happy to try to help if you post the data you used to make the first plot.

Comment: but how to post the data @DaveArmstrong

Comment: You could paste the output of `dput(melteddata)` into a code block.

Comment: i paste the head of dput(data) is it ok or u need whole data @DaveArmstrong

Comment: It all depends on whether we can recreate something that looks like the plot above with the output from `head()`.

Comment: wait i will update the whole data @DaveArmstrong

Comment: You could just put all of `melteddata` rather than having us create it, but either way is fine.

Comment: simply try `facet_wrap(~blade, scale = "free")`  or "free_x". Use `eom_col` instead of bar

Comment: i update the whole data but not in proper format  tried but its showing some error kindly edit that if u need@DaveArmstrong

Comment: thanks roman its help little bit but the major thing is  i need to set legend to all the plot separately @Roman

Answer (score 3):

I think this is close to what you're looking for:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
data=ab%>%filter(site=="BUCHHAINER_HEIDE")
data2 = data[data$wtg==83363,]
melteddata2 = melt(data2, measure.vars = c("bushingdam", "bushing_all_critical"))
melteddata=melt(data2,measure.vars=c("wedgedam_e"))
melteddata3=melt(data2,measure.vars=c("wedgedam_i"))

melteddata2a <- melteddata2 %>% 
  filter(variable == "bushingdam")
melteddata2b <- melteddata2 %>% 
  filter(variable == "bushing_all_critical")

melteddata <- melteddata %>% 
  mutate(blade = factor(blade, levels=c("927", "928", "925", "922")))
h1 <- max(c(melteddata$value, melteddata3$value))
h2 <- max(melteddata2$value)
rat <- h1/h2
melteddata2 <- melteddata2 %>% 
  mutate(plot_value = value*rat)
melteddata3 <- melteddata3 %>% 
  mutate(plot_text = ifelse(value == 0, "", value))

pal <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(4, "Dark2")

ggplot(melteddata,aes(x=date, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',
           position = position_nudge(x=-0.2), 
           width=.15)+
  geom_bar(melteddata2,
           mapping = aes(x=date,y=plot_value,fill=variable),
           stat="identity",
           position = position_nudge(x=+0.2), 
           width=.15)+
  geom_bar(melteddata3,
           mapping = aes(x=date,y=value,fill=variable),
           stat="identity",
           width=.15)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=pal, labels=c("Bushing", "Critical Bushing", "Wedge E", "Wedge I")) + 
  facet_wrap(~melteddata$blade, scales="free_x", nrow=1) + 
  theme(legend.position="top", 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=30, hjust=1))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = function(x)x/rat, 
                                        breaks=c(200, 400, 600, 800), 
                                        name="Bushing Delamination Count [-]")) + 
  ggtitle("wtg83363") + 
  geom_text(data=melteddata3, aes(x=date, y=value, label=plot_text), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7), 
            size=3, col=pal[4]) + 
  geom_text(data=melteddata, aes(x=date, y=value, label=value), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7, x=-.2), 
            size=3, col=pal[3]) + 
geom_text(data=melteddata2a, aes(x=date, y=value*rat, label=value), 
          position=position_nudge(y=7, x=.2), 
          size=3, col=pal[2]) +
geom_text(data=melteddata2b, aes(x=date, y=value*rat, label=value), 
          position=position_nudge(y=7, x=.2), 
          size=3, col=pal[1]) + 
  labs(x="UT Scan Date", y="Wedge Delamination Count [-]", fill="")
```

[image]

---

EDIT:

Updated to include legend in each plot.  Basically requires making 4 different plots and putting them together.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
data=ab%>%filter(site=="BUCHHAINER_HEIDE")
data2 = data[data$wtg==83363,]
melteddata2 = melt(data2, measure.vars = c("bushingdam", "bushing_all_critical"))
melteddata=melt(data2,measure.vars=c("wedgedam_e"))
melteddata3=melt(data2,measure.vars=c("wedgedam_i"))

melteddata2a <- melteddata2 %>% 
  filter(variable == "bushingdam")
melteddata2b <- melteddata2 %>% 
  filter(variable == "bushing_all_critical")

melteddata <- melteddata %>% 
  mutate(blade = factor(blade, levels=c("927", "928", "925", "922")))
h1 <- max(c(melteddata$value, melteddata3$value))
h2 <- max(melteddata2$value)
rat <- h1/h2
melteddata2 <- melteddata2 %>% 
  mutate(plot_value = value*rat)
melteddata3 <- melteddata3 %>% 
  mutate(plot_text = ifelse(value == 0, "", value))

pal <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(4, "Dark2")


m_927 <- melteddata %>% filter(blade == "927")
m2_927 <- melteddata2 %>% filter(blade == "927")
m2a_927 <- melteddata2a %>% filter(blade == "927")
m2b_927 <- melteddata2b %>% filter(blade == "927")
m3_927 <- melteddata3 %>% filter(blade == "927")

g927 <- ggplot(m_927, aes(x=date, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',
           position = position_nudge(x=-0.2), 
           width=.15)+
  geom_bar(m2_927,
           mapping = aes(x=date,y=plot_value,fill=variable),
           stat="identity",
           position = position_nudge(x=+0.2), 
           width=.15)+
  geom_bar(m3_927,
           mapping = aes(x=date,y=value,fill=variable),
           stat="identity",
           width=.15)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=pal, 
                    labels=c("Bushing", "Critical Bushing", "Wedge E", "Wedge I")) + 
  facet_wrap(~blade, scales="free_x", nrow=1) + 
  theme(legend.background = element_blank(), 
        legend.position=c(.5, .95),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.35, "cm"), 
        legend.text = element_text(size=7.5), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=30, hjust=1))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = function(x)x/rat, 
                                         breaks=c(200, 400, 600, 800), 
                                         name="")) + 
  expand_limits(y=c(0,475)) + 
  geom_text(data=m3_927, aes(x=date, y=value, label=plot_text), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7), 
            size=3, col=pal[4]) + 
  geom_text(data=m_927,  aes(x=date, y=value, label=value), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7, x=-.2), 
            size=3, col=pal[3]) + 
  geom_text(data=m2a_927, aes(x=date, y=value*rat, label=value), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7, x=.2), 
            size=3, col=pal[2]) +
  geom_text(data=m2a_927, aes(x=date, y=value*rat, label=value), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7, x=.2), 
            size=3, col=pal[1]) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2)) + 
  labs(x="UT Scan Date", y="Wedge Delamination Count [-]", fill="")

m_928 <- melteddata %>% filter(blade == "928")
m2_928 <- melteddata2 %>% filter(blade == "928")
m2a_928 <- melteddata2a %>% filter(blade == "928")
m2b_928 <- melteddata2b %>% filter(blade == "928")
m3_928 <- melteddata3 %>% filter(blade == "928")

g928 <- ggplot(m_928, aes(x=date, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',
           position = position_nudge(x=-0.2), 
           width=.15)+
  geom_bar(m2_928,
           mapping = aes(x=date,y=plot_value,fill=variable),
           stat="identity",
           position = position_nudge(x=+0.2), 
           width=.15)+
  geom_bar(m3_928,
           mapping = aes(x=date,y=value,fill=variable),
           stat="identity",
           width=.15)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=pal, 
                    labels=c("Bushing", "Critical Bushing", "Wedge E", "Wedge I")) + 
  facet_wrap(~blade, scales="free_x", nrow=1) + 
  theme(legend.background = element_blank(), 
        legend.position=c(.5, .95),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.35, "cm"), 
        legend.text = element_text(size=7.5), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=30, hjust=1))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = function(x)x/rat, 
                                         breaks=c(200, 400, 600, 800), 
                                         name="")) + 
  expand_limits(y=c(0,475)) + 
  geom_text(data=m3_928, aes(x=date, y=value, label=plot_text), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7), 
            size=3, col=pal[4]) + 
  geom_text(data=m_928,  aes(x=date, y=value, label=value), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7, x=-.2), 
            size=3, col=pal[3]) + 
  geom_text(data=m2a_928, aes(x=date, y=value*rat, label=value), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7, x=.2), 
            size=3, col=pal[2]) +
  geom_text(data=m2a_928, aes(x=date, y=value*rat, label=value), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7, x=.2), 
            size=3, col=pal[1]) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2)) + 
  labs(x="UT Scan Date", y="", fill="")

m_925 <- melteddata %>% filter(blade == "925")
m2_925 <- melteddata2 %>% filter(blade == "925")
m2a_925 <- melteddata2a %>% filter(blade == "925")
m2b_925 <- melteddata2b %>% filter(blade == "925")
m3_925 <- melteddata3 %>% filter(blade == "925")

g925 <- ggplot(m_925, aes(x=date, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',
           position = position_nudge(x=-0.2), 
           width=.15)+
  geom_bar(m2_925,
           mapping = aes(x=date,y=plot_value,fill=variable),
           stat="identity",
           position = position_nudge(x=+0.2), 
           width=.15)+
  geom_bar(m3_925,
           mapping = aes(x=date,y=value,fill=variable),
           stat="identity",
           width=.15)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=pal, 
                    labels=c("Bushing", "Critical Bushing", "Wedge E", "Wedge I")) + 
  facet_wrap(~blade, scales="free_x", nrow=1) + 
  theme(legend.background = element_blank(), 
        legend.position=c(.5, .95),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.35, "cm"), 
        legend.text = element_text(size=7.5), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=30, hjust=1))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = function(x)x/rat, 
                                         breaks=c(200, 400, 600, 800), 
                                         name="")) + 
  expand_limits(y=c(0,475)) + 
  geom_text(data=m3_925, aes(x=date, y=value, label=plot_text), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7), 
            size=3, col=pal[4]) + 
  geom_text(data=m_925,  aes(x=date, y=value, label=value), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7, x=-.2), 
            size=3, col=pal[3]) + 
  geom_text(data=m2a_925, aes(x=date, y=value*rat, label=value), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7, x=.2), 
            size=3, col=pal[2]) +
  geom_text(data=m2a_925, aes(x=date, y=value*rat, label=value), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7, x=.2), 
            size=3, col=pal[1]) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2)) + 
  labs(x="UT Scan Date", y="", fill="")

m_922 <- melteddata %>% filter(blade == "922")
m2_922 <- melteddata2 %>% filter(blade == "922")
m2a_922 <- melteddata2a %>% filter(blade == "922")
m2b_922 <- melteddata2b %>% filter(blade == "922")
m3_922 <- melteddata3 %>% filter(blade == "922")

g922 <- ggplot(m_922, aes(x=date, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',
           position = position_nudge(x=-0.2), 
           width=.15)+
  geom_bar(m2_922,
           mapping = aes(x=date,y=plot_value,fill=variable),
           stat="identity",
           position = position_nudge(x=+0.2), 
           width=.15)+
  geom_bar(m3_922,
           mapping = aes(x=date,y=value,fill=variable),
           stat="identity",
           width=.15)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=pal, 
                    labels=c("Bushing", "Critical Bushing", "Wedge E", "Wedge I")) + 
  facet_wrap(~blade, scales="free_x", nrow=1) + 
  theme(legend.background = element_blank(), 
        legend.position=c(.5, .95),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.35, "cm"), 
        legend.text = element_text(size=7.5), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=30, hjust=1))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = function(x)x/rat, 
                                         breaks=c(200, 400, 600, 800), 
                                         name="Bushing Delamination Count [-]")) + 
  expand_limits(y=c(0,475)) + 
  geom_text(data=m3_922, aes(x=date, y=value, label=plot_text), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7), 
            size=3, col=pal[4]) + 
  geom_text(data=m_922,  aes(x=date, y=value, label=value), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7, x=-.2), 
            size=3, col=pal[3]) + 
  geom_text(data=m2a_922, aes(x=date, y=value*rat, label=value), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7, x=.2), 
            size=3, col=pal[2]) +
  geom_text(data=m2a_922, aes(x=date, y=value*rat, label=value), 
            position=position_nudge(y=7, x=.2), 
            size=3, col=pal[1]) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2)) + 
  labs(x="UT Scan Date", y="", fill="")

gridExtra::grid.arrange(g927, g928, g925, g922, nrow=1)
```

[image]

---

EDIT 2: How to autmoate

To automate the construction of the graphs, you could write a function that makes the graph from the data, like below.  The function takes the original raw data, the site to be graphed, the value of the blade (as the `blade_val` argument), the value of the `wtg` variable used to subset the data (as `wtg_val`) and then `left_lab` and `right_lab` as arguments for whether the y-axis labels on the left and/or right should be printed.

```
make_graph <- function(data, site, blade_val, wtg_val=83363, left_lab=TRUE, right_lab=TRUE){
  ll <- ifelse(left_lab, "Wedge Delimation Count [-]", "")
  rl <- ifelse(right_lab, "Bushing Delamination Count [-]", "")
  
  require(dplyr)
  require(reshape2)
  data=data%>%filter(site==site)
  data2 = data[data$wtg==wtg_val,]
  melteddata2 = melt(data2, measure.vars = c("bushingdam", "bushing_all_critical"))
  melteddata=melt(data2,measure.vars=c("wedgedam_e"))
  melteddata3=melt(data2,measure.vars=c("wedgedam_i"))
  
  melteddata2a <- melteddata2 %>% 
    filter(variable == "bushingdam")
  melteddata2b <- melteddata2 %>% 
    filter(variable == "bushing_all_critical")
  
  melteddata <- melteddata %>% 
    mutate(blade = factor(blade, levels=c("927", "928", "925", "922")))
  h1 <- max(c(melteddata$value, melteddata3$value))
  h2 <- max(melteddata2$value)
  rat <- h1/h2
  melteddata2 <- melteddata2 %>% 
    mutate(plot_value = value*rat)
  melteddata3 <- melteddata3 %>% 
    mutate(plot_text = ifelse(value == 0, "", value))
  
  pal <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(4, "Dark2")
  
  
  m <- melteddata %>% filter(blade == blade_val)
  m2 <- melteddata2 %>% filter(blade == blade_val)
  m2a <- melteddata2a %>% filter(blade == blade_val)
  m2b <- melteddata2b %>% filter(blade == blade_val)
  m3 <- melteddata3 %>% filter(blade == blade_val)
  
  g <- ggplot(m, aes(x=date, y=value, fill=variable)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity',
             position = position_nudge(x=-0.2), 
             width=.15)+
    geom_bar(m2,
             mapping = aes(x=date,y=plot_value,fill=variable),
             stat="identity",
             position = position_nudge(x=+0.2), 
             width=.15)+
    geom_bar(m3,
             mapping = aes(x=date,y=value,fill=variable),
             stat="identity",
             width=.15)+
    scale_fill_manual(values=pal, 
                      labels=c("Bushing", "Critical Bushing", "Wedge E", "Wedge I")) + 
    facet_wrap(~blade, scales="free_x", nrow=1) + 
    theme(legend.background = element_blank(), 
          legend.position=c(.5, .95),
          legend.key.size = unit(0.35, "cm"), 
          legend.text = element_text(size=7.5), 
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle=30, hjust=1))+
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = function(x)x/rat, 
                                           breaks=c(200, 400, 600, 800), 
                                           name=rl)) + 
    expand_limits(y=c(0,475)) + 
    geom_text(data=m3, aes(x=date, y=value, label=plot_text), 
              position=position_nudge(y=7), 
              size=3, col=pal[4]) + 
    geom_text(data=m,  aes(x=date, y=value, label=value), 
              position=position_nudge(y=7, x=-.2), 
              size=3, col=pal[3]) + 
    geom_text(data=m2a, aes(x=date, y=value*rat, label=value), 
              position=position_nudge(y=7, x=.2), 
              size=3, col=pal[2]) +
    geom_text(data=m2b, aes(x=date, y=value*rat, label=value), 
              position=position_nudge(y=7, x=.2), 
              size=3, col=pal[1]) + 
    guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2)) + 
    labs(x="UT Scan Date", y=ll, fill="")
  return(g)
}
```

Next, you could find the values of the blades to plot

```
blades <- ab %>% 
  filter(site == "BUCHHAINER_HEIDE" & wtg == 83363) %>% 
  select(blade) %>% 
  distinct %>% 
  pull
```

Then, you could initialize a list that will hold the graphs:

```
glist <- list()
```

Next, loop over all of the values in `blades`, each time making a new graph and storing it in the list.

```
for(i in 1:length(blades)){
  glist[[i]] <- make_graph(ab, 
             site="BUCHHAINER_HEIDE", 
             blade_val=blades[i], 
             wtg_val=83363, 
             left_lab = (i == 1), 
             right_lab = (i == length(blades)))
}
```

We add the `nrow` argument to the list to make sure the graphs are plotted in a single row.

```
glist[["nrow"]] <- 1
```

Finally, we call `grid.arrange()` on the `glist` list and that should produce the graph that adapts to the different numbers of blades per site.

```
do.call(gridExtra::grid.arrange, glist)
```

[image]

Comment: exactly the same but what about the legend for each plot @DaveArmstrong

Comment: @Eliyas Do you need the legend in each plot? The information is exactly the same and in the original graph overplots the bars and numbers.

Comment: @Eliyas I updated the answer - that's as close as I can get, I think.

Comment: It depends on how you want to automate it - what things do you need to iterate over?

Comment: now i take the data only for site=="BUCHHAINER_HEIDE" like wise i have 12 number of sites @DaveArmstrong

Comment: @Eliyas I updated the second code chunk (the one under EDIT).  It should work by just changing the `site` filter in the third line of the code.

Comment: based on the sites the blades is also increase some have 6 some have 7 on that time how to handle that

Comment: @Eliyas I added another edit that gives you a sense of how it could work.

Comment: i appreciate u r effort  @DaveArmstrong  but i need one more help last week i post one question in r shiny .... i updated the code no one is answered till now it was small one only if u r available kindly check that

Comment: using the above iterate code i m getting this error............  Error in make_graph(ab, site = "BUCHHAINER_HEIDE", blade_val = blades[i],  : 
  'edges' must be numeric or character
In addition: Warning message:
In if (class(edges) == "formula") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> glist[["nrow"]] <- 1
> do.call(gridExtra::grid.arrange, glist)
Error in unit(rep(1, ncol), "null") : 
  'x' and 'units' must have length > 0

Comment: @Eliyas Can you send me the data file you're using: dave@quantoid.net

Comment: @Eliyas I also just posted an answer to your other question.

Comment: @Eliyas not sure what you mean by "take python for reference"

Comment: dave@quantoid.net is this u r email id